# How to use R with Google Colaboratory?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory supports Python version 2.7 and 3.6

I saw an example how to use Swift in Colab a while ago.

Today, I happened to run

```
!jupyter-kernelspec list
```

And found a new kernel: IRkernel

```
Available kernels:
  ir         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  swift      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/swift
```

Is it now possible to use R in Colab as well? No hassle in installing R kernel?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Yes.

For a new R-notebook, use [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=r).

You can learn from IRkernel demos, e.g. [demo.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/example-notebooks/Demo.ipynb)

Save a copy in your Google Drive, and make any changes you need.

2 more demos:

- [Display.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/example-notebooks/Display.ipynb) shows how to display HTML, images.
- [Comm_Demo.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/example-notebooks/Comm_Demo.ipynb) shows how to communicate between R and JavaScript.

See more details in [IRkernel Github](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel).

Comment: So one should use this each time one wants to run R on Google Colab?! Running it does return some warning(about non Google authorised). Is it safe?

Comment: and how to install R libraries?

Comment: Just call `install.packages("wordcloud")` to install wordcloud library, for example.

Comment: Do you have to re-install the packages each time you load the notebook?

Comment: Does this answer imply that there is no way to launch an R notebook through an actual Google-built UI, but only a way that involves a secret query-string incantation?

Comment: @Nathan Exactly. 

Comment: All the demo links from colab.fan are down.

Answer (score 50):

In case you want to use Python and R together, you can use R magic for some cells.

```
# activate R magic
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Then, whenever you want to use R, you begin the cell with `%%R`

```
%%R
x <- 42
print(x)
```

More details in [rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/index.html)

Comment: you do not need to run `import rpy2` running the `load_ext` magic is sufficient

Comment: OK, I'll take it out then

Comment: I totally understand that using the magic commands is better than no option at all, but you have to admit that if you wanted to R throughout the entire notebook, is kinda nuts that we would have to add %%R to the top over every single code cell one by one.

Comment: This answer is only good if you want to mix some R into a Python notebook. If you write mostly R, please use my first answer above.

Comment: Also I have troubles installing packages using this method in Colab. I wanted to install one package, call one function from that package and then work with the results in Python. For some packages it works, for some it does not. I get errors with dependencies e.g.```installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status```

Answer (score 22):

Open this link in your browser to create a new notebook with R Kernel

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=r

Answer (score 13):

*********Working as of Friday 13th November 2020****

Go this URL https://colab.to/r whilst signed into colab and that should do it.

You can check if R in Runtime -> Change runtime type, but it should already be setup.

[image]

**To mount google drive:**

```
install.packages("googledrive")
library("googledrive")

if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py")){ 
  install.packages("R.utils")
  library("R.utils")
  library("httr")
  my_check <- function() {return(TRUE)}
  reassignInPackage("is_interactive", pkgName = "httr", my_check)
  options(rlang_interactive=TRUE)
}
```

**And authenticate google drive**

```
drive_auth(use_oob = TRUE, cache = TRUE)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works. However, I still cannot mount my drive. After implementing the code, the “mount drive” drive icon appears on the left panel, but clicking it displays a notification at the bottom left corner that “mounting your google drive is only available on hosted python runtimes”. I don’t know if there’s a workaround, it will be very helpful

Comment: Hi, @Nosey, can you explain a little more about the stage to mount the drive? Are you still able to get the url to get the authentication code? it returns "Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? ". I do not see any "mount drive" icon mentioned by MTerry...

Comment: @ hamagust, perhaps see if this file exists? My python 3.6 directory is empty, python 3.7 has this path. It installs the libraries if I change 3.6 to 3.7 but I can't find my files. I think the answer lies here. I will return when I have time. Please let us know if you solve.

Answer (score 5):

**Update: this doesn't work anymore (july 2020)**.

The above link on answers above takes directly to R notebook, there you have an option change between R or python. It is strange that Google is changing services just like this. Hence stackoverflow not a great platform to promote tools created by profit mongering/data-selling companies.

**Old answer:**

[image]

As of now if you click at `Runtime` on menu bar then choose `Change Runtime Type`, you can choose between R or Python.
[image: Changing runtime in Colab]

Comment: When we click on change runtime type in a new notebook, we just can change the Hardware accelerator option. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like google removed the option to change kernel. Let me dig around and get back  to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems Google is forcing us to use python in google colab.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on a previous answer, here's how you can move dataframes between the R and Python kernels so you can work with both in the same notebook (for example, if you want to load data in with Pandas, process it with an R package, and then plot it with Bokeh).

```
# Pandas dataframe to R data frame
!pip3 install rpy2
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R -i df
```

```
# R data frame to Pandas dataframe
%R seq.data <- read.delim('sequence.index', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
seq_data = %R seq.data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way is to replace postix, .ipynb in colab title to .r  
Example: change name of Untitled.ipynb to Untitled.r, and everything works perfectly!

Comment: I've just tried to do so with working .ipynb notebook, and it didn't help... Does the runtime have to change automatically?