# How to mount google drive to R notebook in colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, mount

I have an R notebook in colab where I want to read a file which is saved in my google drive.

I only seem to find python code such as 
"from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')" to mount the drive.

However, is there code for R to do this or another alternative? I am really struggling and would very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Start using python:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then load the R Magic:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

and then activate the R Magic and load your data:

```
%%R
url = ('/content/drive/myDrive/folder1/myfile.csv')
dataset = read.csv(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

**To mount google drive in an R kernel:**

```
install.packages("googledrive")
library("googledrive")

if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab_ipython.py")){
  install.packages("R.utils")
  library("R.utils")
  library("httr")
  my_check <- function() {return(TRUE)}
  reassignInPackage("is_interactive", pkgName = "httr", my_check)
  options(rlang_interactive=TRUE)
}
```

**And authenticate google drive**

```
drive_auth(use_oob = TRUE, cache = TRUE)
```

Comment: Google Colab says it can't find R.utils

Comment: When I run it from colab.to/r, and do the drive_auth, I get the following:

Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.

Comment: You're nearly there. The options/suggestions are outside the remit of a comment but perhaps check here https://github.com/tidyverse/googledrive/issues/276 or post a question.

Comment: @Nosey answer work, but you have to check if the first condition is `TRUE` by changing Python's version. For example, it worked foo me after changing to Python 3.7 :)
`file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab_ipython.py")`

Comment: Why would we need that `if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab_ipython.py"))` to start with? Can't we just run that inner block without the if?

Comment: Any updates here in 2022?

Comment: After I authorize, it doesn't seem to add the google drive path anywhere in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no mechanism as of now to mount google drive in colab notebook with R kernel. Although a workaround can be used to have google drive mounted normally as in pyhton kernel and use both python and r based on the needs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850904) answer which explains how r and python can be run together.

```
# activate R magic
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R
x <- 42
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

R Colab in 2022:

```
    install.packages("googledrive")
    library("googledrive")
    
    if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py")){
      install.packages("R.utils")
      library("R.utils")
      library("httr")
      my_check <- function() {return(TRUE)}
      reassignInPackage("is_interactive", pkgName = "httr", my_check)
      options(rlang_interactive=TRUE)

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).