# How to write to a file from R Google Colaboratory?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to write output files from R Colaboratory notebook to Google Drive? (standard `write.table` does not write anything to Google Drive)

Answer (score 0):

Colab can easily copy a single file to your googledrive if the drive is mounted. The challenge is for colab to sequentially copy files to your drive from a program generating files. One thing to do is to generate all the files into your colab folder, create a single archive file with tar or zip of the files, and then copy that single archive file to your googledrive.

Answer (score 0):

This post shows a solution to mount Google Drive in Colab using Python notebook and R magic [How to mount google drive to R notebook in colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679549/how-to-mount-google-drive-to-r-notebook-in-colab)