# Workflow for R-Keras on Google Colab

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I would like to do machine learning with R (please accept my choice) and was wondering if I could use the IRkernel on google colab to install and run keras and thereby access the tensorflow library in any way. Is there a working/accessible implementation/example to show me how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself: I host Rmd/jupyter R files on github and open them from github in colab. Because it is a R-jupyter notebook it is automatically opened with the IRkernel. Install keras and you are good to go, as all the necessary tensorflow/python packages are already installed (also selecting CPU/GPU/TPU seems to work without problems).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's feasible. See this post: [How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory) note that I've not tested it.

Comment: I know that I can run R on google colab, but when I try to run: `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")` and `library(keras); install_keras()` I get the following error message: "Error: Error creating virtual environment '~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' [error code 1]", so I think there must be a special workflow to get this running.

Comment: Hi, the question is not about how to use R kernel in Google Colaboratory. The issue is on `keras`, as it has interface with python. Google colab has Python, and if we run `reticulate:py_config()` it will return python3 is existent. But, if we run install_keras() it will complain "could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3"