# How t make a new R notebook in google colab?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I want to make a new R notebook with Google Colab, but I cannot find how to make it. Can you please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory) Maybe [this is an answer for the web interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403667/).

Comment: is this the command:     !jupyter-kernelspec list

Comment: Check rather the answer below for the [web interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403667/), that should help you.