# Installing a python library in an R notebook on Google Colab

Tags: python, r, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install a python library in an R notebook on Google Colab, I use for this the 'reticulate' package:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")
```

But I get as a result this error:

```
Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3
```

Is there a work around this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly in Google Colab but you can share it with local runtime. Google Colab doesn't support installing a new version of python or R. If you are in R notebook you can only use R because there is no python installed on the Colab cloud computer. But if you connect with your local runtime you can use those functions.

For more you can check these links:

[How to use R and Python with Google Colaboratory Notebook?](https://medium.com/@ezzaouia/how-to-use-r-and-python-with-google-colaboratory-notebook-ebc4774d48a)

[How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory)