# how do you tell a Colab cell to execute all code in R?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I am new to Colab.
How do you tell a Google Colab cell your code is in R?

If this is not the place to ask this question, do you have suggestion as to the correct place?

I appreciate your patience with me...

Comment: Try this : [How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory/54595286#54595286) (I didn't try it).

Comment: Try starting a collab from this link: *https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=r* . I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but it seems to be pretty simple.