# How to write R in colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

How to change the interface to R. I can't find the option in Runtime. When I select change runtime type, it doesn't provide to change it to R or any other programming language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 1):

Start [*rmagic*](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/interactive.html) by executing the following command:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

In subsequent cells use `%%R` to run R code:

```
%%R
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=50)
x
```

## Example

[image: Colab with R]