# How to access the shell in google Colab when running the R kernel

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

When I use Python with colab, you can access the underlying operating system using things like `!` and `%%shell`, e.g., `!ls` to list the files.

When I use colab with the R kernel, the `!` and `%%shell` tricks don't work.  Is there a way to call the shell from colab in this case?

https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true&language=r

Comment: Not sure if you are interested in workarounds, but you could use `system2("ls", stdout = TRUE)` instead (or `list.files()`).

Comment: Good idea, that might be the best option if there's no shorter way to do it.  As for things like `list.files()`, that's exactly the kind of thing I've been doing (e.g.,`download.file(...)` instead of `wget`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the base R function `system` which allows you to call the shell behind the Notebook. Since colab suppresses the stdout, one needs to set the option `intern = TRUE` to see the result as an R character vector. To properly display line breaks, I defined a function called `shell_call` which is analog to `!` in ipython:

```
shell_call <- function(command, ...) {
  result <- system(command, intern = TRUE, ...)
  cat(paste0(result, collapse = "\n"))
}

shell_call("ls -lah / | head")
```

[image]

Comment: That's basically what I've already suggested in a comment (except for using `system` - see`?system`: `This interface has become rather complicated over the years: see system2 for a more portable and flexible interface which is recommended for new code.`).

Comment: Ipythons `!` behavior is more of the function `system` instead of `system2`:  You can not just simply write `system2("ls -lah /", stdout = TRUE)`. Furthermore, it returns a character vector instead of a formatted text. This is why I defined the function `!`

Comment: Sure - we could write a wrapper for `system2` in a similar fashion but personally I wouldn't want to overwrite the logical operator `!` in R.

Comment: I revised my answer to not overload `!`

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of magics is kernel specific as explained [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#built-in-magic-commands):

> To Jupyter users: Magics are specific to and provided by the IPython
> kernel. Whether Magics are available on a kernel is a decision that is
> made by the kernel developer on a per-kernel basis. To work properly,
> Magics must use a syntax element which is not valid in the underlying
> language. For example, the IPython kernel uses the % syntax element
> for Magics as % is not a valid unary operator in Python. However, %
> might have meaning in other languages.

R does not offer good conditions to implement magics this way as for example `%%` is used as the modulo operator and `!` as the logical NOT operator.

This is why the developers of the IRkernel have chosen not to support %%cell magic - see [this](https://irkernel.github.io/faq/) or [this](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/260#issuecomment-185888884).

As already outlined in the comments when working with the IRkernel you'll need to find solutions in the R language itself e.g. using built-in functions to access the shell `system2("ls", stdout = TRUE)` or search for files `list.files()` (you might also want to wrap them in a custom function as suggested by @danlooo).

If you still want to use magics another approach would be to use R magics (extension rmagic) along with the IPython kernel as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850904/9841389) or [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/version0.13.html#cell-magics):

[image: result]